# Pagination in django not working for first page

Tags: python, django

Am currently implementing pagination in django. I have a problem when i try to click a button that is supposed to redirect me back to the first page or even get the content of the first page.

views.py

```
    else:
        all_tasks = TaskList.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(all_tasks, 5)
        page = request.GET.get('pg')

        all_tasks = paginator.get_page(page)


        context = {
            'all_tasks': all_tasks
        }
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

html code

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?pg=1">First</a></li>
    {% if all_tasks.has_previous %}
     
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?pg={{ all_tasks.previous_page_number }}">{{ all_tasks.previous_page_number }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}

      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?pg={{ all_tasks.number }}">{{ all_tasks.number }}</a></li>
    
    {% if all_tasks.has_next %}
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?pg={{ all_tasks.previous_page_number }}">{{ all_tasks.previous_page_number }}</a></li>
     
    {% endif %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?pg={{ all_tasks.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a></li>
   
  </ul>
</nav>
```

When i click "first" django throws those errors. Kindly assist.
error that django is throwing is this

```
EmptyPage at /task/
That page number is less than 1
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/task/
Django Version: 3.1.5
Exception Type: EmptyPage
Exception Value:    
That page number is less than 1
Exception Location: C:\Users\BernardMuendi\.virtualenvs\TaskMate-R1pilZ9L\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py, line 50, in validate_number
Python Executable:  C:\Users\BernardMuendi\.virtualenvs\TaskMate-R1pilZ9L\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.6
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\BernardMuendi\\Desktop\\TaskMate\\taskmate',
 'c:\\program files\\python38\\python38.zip',
 'c:\\program files\\python38\\DLLs',
 'c:\\program files\\python38\\lib',
 'c:\\program files\\python38',
 'C:\\Users\\BernardMuendi\\.virtualenvs\\TaskMate-R1pilZ9L',
 'C:\\Users\\BernardMuendi\\.virtualenvs\\TaskMate-R1pilZ9L\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 16 Feb 2021 09:49:50 +0000
```

Comment: I have 16 tasks added in my database.

Comment: try this [**all_tasks = paginator.get_page(page) --> all_tasks = paginator.page(page)**]

Comment: can you kindly use "answer the question button" and format your proposed solution and where to inject it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

all_tasks = TaskList.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(all_tasks, 5)
page = request.GET.get('pg', 1)
try:       
   all_tasks = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    all_tasks = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
   all_tasks = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

Refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/

Comment: Men i have done it the way you have shown but still the same error, infact it cannot even paginate now. All content is displayed in "?pg=2"

Answer (score 0):

Easy debug process: Check what you are getting in `page = request.GET.get('pg')`
Below is the internal code for `paginator.get_page(page)`. So check why `int(number)` is coming less than 1.

```
def validate_number(self, number):
    """Validate the given 1-based page number."""
    try:
        if isinstance(number, float) and not number.is_integer():
            raise ValueError
        number = int(number)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        raise PageNotAnInteger(_('That page number is not an integer'))
    if number < 1:
        raise EmptyPage(_('That page number is less than 1'))
    if number > self.num_pages:
        if number == 1 and self.allow_empty_first_page:
            pass
        else:
            raise EmptyPage(_('That page contains no results'))
    return number

def get_page(self, number):
    """
    Return a valid page, even if the page argument isn't a number or isn't
    in range.
    """
    try:
        number = self.validate_number(number)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        number = 1
    except EmptyPage:
        number = self.num_pages
    return self.page(number)
```

Comment: I really dont know bro. i have followed Django docs step by step, nothing is working for me

Comment: what you are getting when clicking on 'First'? add a `print('\n\n', request.GET.get('pg'), '\n\n')`  in your view to check. this will print on the console where your server is running

Comment: I know the issue, i passed in .previous_page_number to a .has_next if statement. I have resolved it. Thanks